# Understanding derivation of fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have a general formula of
$$D = P_0 + \epsilon_1 E + \epsilon_2 E^2 + \epsilon_3 E^3 + ...$$

with $D$ as the electrical displacement, $E$ the electrical field, $P_0$ for the polarization at zero-field and $\epsilon$ the permittivity ->  [Source](https://electrons.wikidot.com/direction-electric-field-dependence-of-dielectric-constant)

With $E(t) = E cos(\omega t)$,

$$ D(t) = P_0 + \epsilon_1^*E_0 cos(wt) + \epsilon_2^*E_0^2 cos(2wt) + \epsilon_3^*E_0^3 cos(3wt)+ ...$$

and $D = \epsilon E$,

How do I go from:
$$ D(t) = D_0 + D_1cos(wt) + D_2cos(2wt) + D_3cos(3wt)+ ...$$
to
$$ D_0^* = P_0 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_2^*E_0^2 + \frac{3}{8}\epsilon_4^*E_0^4 + ... $$
$$ D_1^* = \epsilon_1^*E_0 + \frac{3}{4}\epsilon_3^*E_0^3 + \frac{10}{16}\epsilon_5^*E_0^5... $$
$$ D_2^* = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_2^*E_0^2 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_4^*E_0^4 + \frac{15}{32}\epsilon_6^*E_0^6... $$
$$ D_3^* = \frac{1}{4}\epsilon_3^*E_0^3 + \frac{5}{16}\epsilon_5^*E_0^5 + \frac{21}{64}\epsilon_7^*E_0^7... $$

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Fourier Transformation/Series but I'm not sure how to derive them.

Comment: Unless you define $D_0, D_1, ...$ you are better off going to physics stack exchange where they might know what those things mean.

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks for that info. As far as i can understand, the index = 1,2,3... are the coefficients of the respective angular frequencies. D0, D1 etc aren't further elaborated in the article, which is what I'm struggling to understand right now. I'll bring my problem over there later if I don't get any response here.

Comment: You can get proper formatting for operators like $\cos$ using `\cos`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.